# Can you use a video overlay for loading instead of manually animating?

Tags: html, css, animation, loading

Just started learning HTML and CSS 2 days ago. I was wondering if you could use a loading overlay instead of manually animating. Thank you!

Comment: You have the [<progress>-tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) or simply can use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) in combination with a [position: non-static](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, but I suspect you would like to put some text over the video as well, so you have to consider the opacity and the z-index of both the video and the text. Considering you just started learning a few days ago, using youtube will be helpful.

Comment: to borad and unspecific for an answer. This would have been appropiate as a comment but nto as an answer. Use the naswer option only for definete solution not to tell the OP to use tuorials or youtube.